# Script Activity in ADF does not take the new parameter values for Dynamic Link service

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, linked-service

I have Dynamic Link Service created in ADF with parameters to pass the values dynamically whenever i want to change the server's name in Linked service. I am using this link service in Script Activity in Pipeline.

For first time, script activity works fine. After i change the server name, it does not take the new server name by default.
For example, i created Linked service with Dev SQL Server. I create Script activity in Pipeline. It works fine for Dev. if i change SQL Server name in Dynamic Linked Service to QA server. Script activity is still pointing to Dev Server. It does not take new parameter value.

I tried changing the parameter value. Same scenario works fine for Data Service which i used in copydata in Pipeline

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced the above and able to change the server name in script activity successfully.

First, I have created linked service(Azure SQL database) parameters.

[image]

Don't give any default values.
Given the parameters like below.

[image]

Then in Script activity, given pipeline parameters to it. You can directly give values using dynamic content. For sample I have given a select query.

[image]

I have two SQL servers `rakeshserver` and `rakeshserver2`. While debugging it will ask values for pipeline parameter values. If you gave values using dynamic content in script activity, then it executes directly.

**first server and table in first server:**

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

**Second server and table in second server:**

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

If your Script activity is giving the result for same server means, taking the default value might be the reason for it. **Give the parameter value either during debug or using dynamic content then it may work as above**.